# How to retrieve a boost::variant value for a templated class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, boost, boost-variant

I am trying to use the boost::variant in c++11 to create this but I m not sure how.
So I have this structure of the templated class data<>

```
typedef boost::variant< data<A>,data<B>> dataVar;
```

stored in a

`std::map<string,dataVar> dataMap`

It would be great if I could retrieve the type for data somehow so I can assign the values but I have no idea how to make this work elegantly

```
void registerDataFor(string str)
  {
     auto itr = dataMap.find(str);

    if(itr == dataMap.end())
        return;

     dataVar = itr->second;
     data<v.which()> itemData= boost::get<v.which()>(v);
     someArray.push_back(itemData.getIntegerValue());
     registerDataFor(itemData.getString());
  }
```

This doesn't compile since the template brackets require a static type.

I ve seen other responses proposing a visitor design but I also need the type for data<> to get the item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that both `data<A>` and `data<B>` have the same interface, you can use a visitor `struct` with a `template` `operator()`:

```
struct registerImpl : boost::static_visitor<void>
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T& x) const
    {
        someArray.push_back(x.getIntegerValue());
        registerDataFor(x.getString());   
    }
};
```

```
void registerDataFor(std::string str)
{
    auto itr = dataMap.find(str);

    if(itr == dataMap.end())
        return;

    registerImpl visitor;
    boost::apply_visitor(visitor, itr->second);
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/P1IZlArN9444TuNQ)

---

In C++14, you can visit the variant *in place* by using a [generic lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

```
void registerDataFor(std::string str)
{
    auto itr = dataMap.find(str);

    if(itr == dataMap.end())
        return;

    boost::apply_visitor([](auto& x){
        someArray.push_back(x.getIntegerValue());
        registerDataFor(x.getString());      
    }, itr->second);
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/eqj0RJUb1VfikV7l)

---

*(If you are interested in variant visitation using lambdas and C++14 features, I've written two articles about it: [**part 1**](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/variants_lambdas_part_1.html) and [**part 2**](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/variants_lambdas_part_2.html).)*

Comment: The C++14 solution is sufficiently more awesome I would suggest including it, even in a C++11 question.  :)